# How can I use .editorconfig in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, webstorm, editorconfig

Is there a way to sync code style config between WebStorm and VSCode?

I've exported the config in WebStorm into `.editorconfig` file. How can I use it in VSCode?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/create-portable-custom-editor-options?view=vs-2022 Check this Link

Comment: @Voidy ok thanks but my IDE is VsCode Not Visual Studio Code

Comment: Isnt VsCode the short of Visual Studio Code?

Comment: And do you have the "EditorConfig for vs code" Extension installed?

Comment: the link applies to VS not VSC, AFAIK VSC does not support EditorConfig out of the box, maybe there is an extension that converts to VSC format

Comment: Type "editorconfig" in the extension pane (View/ Extensions).